# How to reverse a URL from RegexURLPattern in django 1.8?

Tags: django, django-urls, django-1.8

I got a django 1.8 app where the admin app and all other apps are on separate instances. I want to be able to reverse a url from one of the apps in the admin site. This is the pattern (from one of the app's urls.py):

```
 url(r'/invoice/(?P<uid>[^/]+)/$',
     transaction_views.invoice,
     name='transaction-invoice'),
```

Because the Url's are not available in the admin site it's not possible to simply use `reverse('transaction-invoice', args=[tx.uuid])` but since the code is there I have access to the `RegexURLPattern` object.

Is it possible to generate the url from the objects (preferably without resorting to using the actual regexp) and also set the base url (from a `Site` object)?

Comment: Why do you say the urls aren't available in the admin? They are, and you can use the `reverse` function as normal.

Comment: have you tried using reverse? it should work so long as the application is in your installed apps settings.

Comment: @DanielRoseman, As mentioned, the admin is mounted on a different instance where the transaction app is not installed so the Invoice pattern is not available in the default URL resolver used by reverse.